# In Node.js, If i am writing a long running function should I be using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

or something else to queue up the rest of my function? and use callbacks or does node handle that automatically?

I imagine that I would need to start my code and if there are other things that  need to occur I should be giving up my functions control to give other events control. Is this the case? Or can i be stingy and node will cut off my function when I have used enough time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your long-running function does a lot of I/O just make sure that you do this in a non-blocking way. This is how node.js achieves concurrency even though it only has a single thread: As soon as any task needs to wait for something, another task gets the CPU.

If your long-running function needs uninterrupted CPU time (or the I/O cannot be made asynchronously) , then you probably need to fork out a separate process, because otherwise every one else will have to wait until you are done.

> Or can i be stingy and node will cut off my function when I have used enough time?

No. This is totally cooperative multi-tasking. Node cannot preempt you.

Answer (score 3):

You should put your long running function or the code which takes long to execute into separate process because it can, for example, block other incoming requests while this code/function is executing. From [node.js](http://nodejs.org) website:

> But what about multiple-processor concurrency? Aren't threads
>   necessary to scale programs to multi-core computers? You can start new
>   processes via child_process.fork() these other processes will be
>   scheduled in parallel.

I would suggest to watch these articles/presentations in order to get a bigger picture on this topic:

- [Understanding the node.js event loop](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/)
- [Understanding event loops and writing great code for Node.js](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/understanding-the-event-loops-and-writing-great-code-for-node-js-part-1/)
- [YUI Theater — Tom Hughes-Croucher: “How to Stop Writing Spaghetti Code” (45 min.)](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/06/video-yuiconf2010-croucher/)